# React invariant violation when passing a component as a prop to another component

Tags: reactjs, components, typeahead

I'm working on a project that uses [react-typeahead](https://github.com/fmoo/react-typeahead) and attempting to implement a custom component for the dropdown list. React-typeahead accepts a customListComponent prop.

However, I need to pass a prop to the component that is being passed into the Typeahead component. Initially, I tried setting a variable as a the custom component:

```js
//MainSearch.js
import SearchOrderComponent from './SearchOrderComponent'

export default class MainSearch extends React.Component {
    //Constructor here

    render() {
       let customList = <SearchOrderComponent ranking={this.state.ranking} />
       return(
           <div className="search-container">
              <Typeahead customListComponent={customList} />
           </div>
       )
    }
}
```

This caused an invariant violation, with react stating that a react component was expected. My current workaround is to make `SearchOrderComponent` a function that accepts the paren't state as an input and returns a react component, like so:

```js
//SearchOrderComponent.js
const wrapper = function(ranking){
   let SearchOrder = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        var searchRanking = ranking.map(function(item){
           return <li key={item.key}>{item.value.niceName}</li>
        });

        return(
           <div className='main-dropdown'>
              {searchRanking}
           </div>
        );
      }
   });
   return SearchOrder;
}

module.exports = wrapper;
```

Now I can input this function directly into the typeahead component:

```js
//MainSearch.js
<Typeahead customListComponent={SearchOrderComponent(this.state.ranking)} />
```

But this feels like a break from the component API. Is there a more direct/proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, the most direct way would be

```
render() {
   return(
       <div className="search-container">
          <Typeahead>
            <SearchOrderComponent ranking={this.state.ranking} />
          </Typeahead>
       </div>
   )
}
```

You can access the `SearchOrderComponent` from within the `Typeahead` component via `this.props.children`.